# Samsung s5 server password has been changed. Input the changed password

Tags: google-account

Suddenly my phone keeps popping up with this message in the notifications bar >sign in failed<.  I go to the email and the message says >password has been changed.  Input the changed password<.  At first I put in my password and it did not work.  I went to the internet to login and could not and then changed my password.

Everything seemed fine for about 20 mins and then the message popped up again.  This time I have not typed in the password and I can still access my email from the gmail app on my phone. But everytime i get an email my phone brings up this message!

I had just deleted an app that my phone said was a security risk so I am unsure if it had anything to with that? Although I can still use my account on both phone and tablet I am only getting the message on my phone.

Can you help?

---

yes I changed the password and signed in again to my accounts again including this one and then a little while later the message come up again.

I have often been confused by my email account on my phone so I will try my best to explain....the gmail on the phone is the one that says I can't access until I put in the changed password but the gmail widget on my phone works fine and I have this email address attached to Outlook with another email address (all working).

Comment: When you changed your password from your computer, did you input a different password than the one you had before?

Comment: Sounds like someone hijacked your account.

Comment: yes I changed the password to a different one.

Comment: Then hijacking of your account is *unlikely*, unless of course there is an app on your phone with the permission to log into your account and change the password.

Answer (score 1):

My mom was having the same problem you have to log off from gmail and sign in again which means going to settings manage accounts and tap remove account then you log in again and you should be good